# Target sibling element when child element is checked

Tags: html, css, sass

I am implementing an accordion with just HTML and CSS. I use an hidden checkbox and the `:checked` state to trigger the collapsible inner part of the accordion.

The header part has a text label and a checkbox that will be customized with an icon, therefore I wrapped these elements in a Flex parent to align them. The issue I am facing is that I need to build a condition that targets the `COLLAPSIBLE` div, sibling of the `HEADER`, when the checkbox (header's child) is checked.

**My Template:**

```
<div class="accordion-container rounded">

  <div class="accordion-header flex-center-y">
    <!-- I would style the checkbox to have a custom icon as content -->
    <input id="accordion1" class="accordion-toggle" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="accordion1" class="lbl-toggle">
      <strong>Header label</strong>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-collapsible"> <!-- This is the part that should expand when checkbox is checked -->
    <div class="accordion-inner-content">
      <p class="accordion-inner-text">
        Inside an accordion content...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.accordion-container {
  padding: 2.15em;
  border: 1px solid black;

  .accordion-header {
    .accordion-toggle {
     // In a second version the checkbox with the icon will be visible.
     // In this version it is not displayed (only the label is visible in this case)
     display: none;
    }
  }

  .accordion-collapsible {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in-out;
  }
  

  // I would need something similar to the rule below:
  // set max-height to accordion-collapsible if the child of accordion-header is checked 
  (.accordion-header > .accordion-toggle:checked) + .accordion-collapsible {
    max-height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

If I remove the `.accordion-header` div and I keep the `checkbox` and the `.accordion-collapsible` div as sibling, the logic works with the following rule, but I would lose the possibility to align the elements in the header (other elements, like buttons, might potentially be added after the label):

```
.accordion-toggle:checked + .accordion-collapsible {
    max-height: 100vh;
  }
```

Is there a way to expand the `.accordion-collapsible` div, when the checkbox is clicked?
If possible I would keep the header as it allows me to nicely align its content.

Comment: No, you can not do this, if you wrap the checkbox input into additional elements. _Sibling_ is the relevant keyword here.

Comment: Not with this HTML, you can't target an element that is outside of the parent (in this case the parent's sibling...you need JS.

Comment: But since you probably don’t want the actual checkbox visible here, you can place it somewhere, where it _is_ a sibling of the target element. For any visual display that is supposed to reflect the current state, you can then format the `label` element, depending on the checkbox status.

Comment: In the case of not showing a custom icon (for the checkbox state) I can move it above the header and it would work fine. But I also have the case, where I should show a toggle icon at the left of the label, therefore I would use the checkbox to show a + or - for the open/close state.